# synaptic support for Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04

I need to use this old version of ubuntu for something and I've found that I cant reload the synaptic list, instead it says it cant find anything. Does anyone know if it's possible to change the settings so that this works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As superuser, change /etc/apt/sources.list to the following:

`deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted universe multiverse`

`deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted universe multiverse`

`deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security main restricted universe multiverse`